# ProcessException: Could not initialize class com.android.tools.analytics.UsageTracker

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

Installed Flutter and Android Studio for the first time, and no issues on the flutter doctor command. Whenever resolving dependencies in gradle this error pops up:

( Already tried it on VS Code too and also tried running the flutter run command in cmd. Can't find other solutions with the same error. Flutter is on v1.0.0-stable, Android Studio is on 3.3.0, Gradle is on 4.10.0. )

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\flutter_testing\flutter_testing\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\flutter_testing\flutter_testing\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not initialize class com.android.tools.analytics.UsageTracker
```

My app/build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.fluttertesting"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
```

Ran ./gradlew --info:

> Found daemon DaemonInfo{pid=10000, address=[a4c9b767-6398-477b-9887-0e151d59998c port:59476, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1550412754629, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=a02c6e0c-fcab-4be0-a907-c9b6b8c8238d,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users[name].gradle\daemon,pid=10000,idle
>   Timeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536M,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} however its context does not match the desired criteria.
>
> Java home is different.
>
> Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users[name].gradle\daemon,pid=5356,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536
>   M,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
>
> Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=a02c6e0c-fcab-4be0-a907-c9b6b8c8238d,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users[name].gradle\daemon,pid=
>   10000,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-Xmx1536M,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
>
> Looking for a different daemon...
>   The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 3404). The daemon log file: C:\Users\Trish Moreno.gradle\daemon\4.10.2\daemon-3404.out.log
>   Starting 3rd build in daemon [uptime: 26 mins 44.709 secs, performance: 95%, no major garbage collections]
>   Using 4 worker leases.
>   Starting Build
>   Settings evaluated using settings file 'D:\flutter_testing\flutter_testing\android\settings.gradle'.
>   Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'D:\flutter_testing\flutter_testing\android\build.gradle'.
>   Included projects: [root project 'android', project ':app']
>
> Configure project :app
>   Evaluating project ':app' using build file 'D:\flutter_testing\flutter_testing\android\app\build.gradle'.
>
> Configure project :
>   Evaluating root project 'android' using build file 'D:\flutter_testing\flutter_testing\android\build.gradle'.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>     Build file 'D:\flutter_testing\flutter_testing\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>     Could not initialize class com.android.tools.analytics.UsageTracker

Any solutions for this?

UPDATE: Found out something new. If I turn on Offline work in Gradle on Android Studio (Project Structure > Build Tools > Gradle), the error becomes com/google/protobuf/ProtocolMessageEnum. Sorry I'm new to this so if anyone can explain why this happens it'll help.

UPDATE 2: Found a workaround, I created another fresh Windows user account and ran flutter from there, and it works. I think this problem has something to do with my Gradle/Android Studio setup? (I uninstalled an older version of AS way back, with the old gradle versions retained, then reinstalled a newer version if AS)

Comment: There may be more details if you run Gradle with debug or info flags -- you need to look at and understand the stacktrace. And maybe show your build.gradle. Also, make sure you understand the Analytics setup as per Google: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/ (Pay attention to the Firebase stuff if you use that.)

Comment: Found out something new. If I turn on Offline work in Gradle on Android Studio (Project Structure > Build Tools > Gradle), the error becomes com/google/protobuf/ProtocolMessageEnum. Sorry I'm new to this so if anyone can explain why this happens it'll help.

Comment: Remember to [edit] and update the question with details like this. Comments can be deleted and are not part of the question.

Comment: You probably want to share the app specific build.gradle, not the top level one. This is hinted at in your info output.

Comment: just edited. here you go.